# Split a text file if two consecutive lines almost identical

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, text-files

I need to split a text file (using a .bat command) based on the content of the string of the previous line (from position 2 to 13) and the content of the string of the current line (from position 2 to 13)...

I explain:

My file looks like that:

```
IA1234567890A         XX33              AZE
bla1                  XX34              DES
bla2                  XX34              DES
bla3                  XX34              DES
FA1234567890A         XX35              AZE
IA1234567890A         XX36              AZE
bla4                  XX34              DES
bla5                  XX34              DES
bla6                  XX34              DES
FA1234567890A         XX37              AZE
IB0987654321A         XX38              AZE
bla7                  XX34              DES
bla8                  XX34              DES
bla9                  XX34              DES
FB0987654321A         XX39              AZE
```

I want to split the file when the first 12 characters of one line starting with "I" (without taking into account the "I") are different than the first 12 characters of the previous line (which is always starting with a "F" except for the first line, but the comparison should not take into account the "F").

So I would not split the file between these two lines:

```
FA1234567890A         XX35              AZE
IA1234567890A         XX36              AZE
```

but I would split the file between these two lines:

```
FA1234567890A         XX37              AZE
IB0987654321A         XX38              AZE
```

I know how to split a file using a delimiter, but I am totally lost with this comparison thing...

I would really appreciate if one of you could help me of this tricky case...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input file is large, this method should run faster because it does not check *all the lines*. It also correctly process lines with special Batch characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read the first line, and create a dummy previous "endLine" with same name
set /P "endName=" < test.txt
set "endName=F%endName:~1%"
set startLine=1
set "startName="

rem Redirect the input file to a code block, in order to read it
< test.txt (

   rem Locate all lines that start with "I" or "F"
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ('findstr /N /B "I F" test.txt') do (
      if not defined startName (
         set "startName=%%b"
         if "!startName:~1,12!" neq "!endName:~1,12!" (
            rem New section starts: copy it to its own file
            set /A lines=endLine-startLine+1
            (for /L %%i in (1,1,!lines!) do (
               set /P "line="
               echo !line!
            )) > "Part !endName:~1,12!.txt"
            set "endName=F%startName:~1%"
            set "startLine=%%a"
         )
      ) else (
         set "endLine=%%a"
         set "endName=%%b"
         set "startName="
      )
   )

   rem Copy last section to its own file
   findstr "^" > "Part !endName:~1,12!.txt"
)
```

Output:

```
C:\> type Part*.txt

Part A1234567890A.txt


IA1234567890A         XX33              AZE
bla1                  XX34              DES
bla2                  XX34              DES
bla3                  XX34              DES
FA1234567890A         XX35              AZE
IA1234567890A         XX36              AZE
bla4                  XX34              DES
bla5                  XX34              DES
bla6                  XX34              DES
FA1234567890A         XX37              AZE

Part B0987654321A.txt


IB0987654321A         XX38              AZE
bla7                  XX34              DES
bla8                  XX34              DES
bla9                  XX34              DES
FB0987654321A         XX39              AZE
```

Answer (score 1):

This reads from `data.txt` and creates `output1.txt`, `output2.txt`, ... `outputn.txt`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set outputcount=0
set previousblock=

for /f "delims=" %%s in (data.txt) do (
  set line=%%s
  set currentblock=!line:~1,13!

  if "!line:~0,1!" EQU "I" (
    if "!previousblock!" NEQ "!currentblock!" (
        set /A outputcount=!outputcount!+1
    )
  )

  echo !line!>>output!outputcount!.txt
  set previousblock=!currentblock!    
)
```

e.g.

```
D:\scripts>splitfile.bat
D:\scripts>type output*

output1.txt


IA1234567890A         XX33              AZE
bla1                  XX34              DES
bla2                  XX34              DES
bla3                  XX34              DES
FA1234567890A         XX35              AZE
IA1234567890A         XX36              AZE
bla4                  XX34              DES
bla5                  XX34              DES
bla6                  XX34              DES
FA1234567890A         XX37              AZE

output2.txt


IB0987654321A         XX38              AZE
bla7                  XX34              DES
bla8                  XX34              DES
bla9                  XX34              DES
FB0987654321A         XX39              AZE
```

### Edit

updated code to make it work.

Comment: Great. what can he change to not break at Output2.txt as he don't want to break

Comment: Haha, thank you - I was so caught up in making it run at all, I didn't notice that it does the wrong thing. I've edited the code to (hopefully) correct it.

Comment: Thanks Arun! Was not expecting such a quick solution!!!

But your solution splits my data in 3 output files... Just like it would just take into account the "I" at the beginning of a line to split the file just before. I am wondering if there should not be a 
    =!line:~1,12!
in the
    set previousblock=
?

Comment: @CHRISTIAN I think I've fixed that, now it only outputs two files. I was doing the substring tests a bit badly, including the first character in the comparision; the first setpreviousblock= is supposed to initialise it empty just for neatness, mostly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh

## clean any split files (got created in previous runs)
rm split.*;

## define variables, ct=counter for reading next line, cnt=counter for creating split.X file and file=split filename
ct=2
cnt=1
file="split.$cnt";

## Read line with spaces, IFS=''
IFS=''
while read lineP
do
  ## Read next line and increment ct variable
  lineN="$(sed -n "${ct}p" inputfile.txt)" && ((ct++))

  ## Read first character of two lines and the next 12 characters
  lineP121=${lineP:0:1} && lineN121=${lineN:0:1}
  lineP1212=${lineP:1:12} && lineN1212=${lineN:1:12}

  ## Match / Condition
  if [[ "$lineP1212" != "$lineN1212" && ( "$lineP121" == "F" && "$lineN121" == "I" ) ]];
  then
   echo "${lineP}:" >> $file;
   ((++cnt));
   file="split.$cnt";
  else
   echo -e "$lineP\n" >> $file;
  fi
done < inputfile.txt

echo -e "\n\nFile created are (with contents in split.X files):\n\n"
ls -l split.* && echo && grep -n . split.* && echo
```

**Output** is: No. of files created 2 split.1 and split.2 files (as per the inputfile).

```
File created are (with contents in split.X files. Output generated by grep -n command. You can use simple cat command if you want):


-rw-r--r-- 1 koba loki 450 Jun  3 19:01 split.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 koba loki 225 Jun  3 19:01 split.2

split.1:1:IA1234567890A         XX33              AZE
split.1:3:bla1                  XX34              DES
split.1:5:bla2                  XX34              DES
split.1:7:bla3                  XX34              DES
split.1:9:FA1234567890A         XX35              AZE
split.1:11:IA1234567890A         XX36              AZE
split.1:13:bla4                  XX34              DES
split.1:15:bla5                  XX34              DES
split.1:17:bla6                  XX34              DES
split.1:19:FA1234567890A         XX37              AZE:

split.2:1:IB0987654321A         XX38              AZE
split.2:3:bla7                  XX34              DES
split.2:5:bla8                  XX34              DES
split.2:7:bla9                  XX34              DES
split.2:9:FB0987654321A         XX39              AZE
```

Comment: But that's not a Windows batch file...  (see question tags)

Comment: See, I missed that. Voting you up.